# valid/invalid Email format policy difference between ColdFusion and PHP

Tags: php, validation, coldfusion

I am neither here to make a war between PHP and ColdFusion people nor to find out which language is better than other. So please give reasonable arguments for this particular point.

I am also not sure whether this kind of question fits into the policy of stackoverflow. But here it is

If you validate email address **test@testdomain** in ColdFusion, it says it's valid email address. but if you test the email address in PHP, it says it's an invalid email address.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), this is valid email address. Please search term admin@mailserver1 (local domain name with no TLD)

My question is that why there is a difference in the implementation and the reasons behind it.

**ColdFusion Code**

```
<cfdump var="#isValid("email","test@testdomain")#">
```

Output

```
Yes
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$email = "test@testdomain";
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid"; 
}
else
{
 $emailErr = "valid";
}

echo $emailErr; 
?>
```

Output

```
Invalid
```

Comment: I think that PHP is just helping developers, as in the most cases you want to validate emails of third parties. And they are very likely (like 99,9% sure) to have emails outside local server, or even if on local, then accessible with some domain in TLD scope. That's only my theory, but personally I'm happy with PHP validation even if it's not following standarized email specifications.

Comment: @Forien, I also think that for 99.9% of the time, you have to validate emails with TLD. Few hours ago, I didn't even aware of the fact that there can be email addresses without TLD.

Comment: I knew that. What I did not know, is that there can be emails like `"   "@example.com`. Weird.

Comment: I understand your question, and would be interested in the answer... but I would suggest to anyone using regex's or inbuilt language features to test email validity, just don't.  With the ability for anyone to buy their own "TLD" these days, the days of validating against the usual suspects of a few years ago is long over.

Comment: Pretty sure the only ones who can answer why there is a difference and why each chose the way they did are the engineers at Adobe and those who contributed the code to PHP.

Comment: *not sure whether this kind of question fits into the policy of stackoverflow* Probably not. Though the anatomy of a "valid" email is an interesting topic, any answers about the implementation will just be guesses/opinions.

Comment: @Jarede, Agreed! I will explore this topic over next week. If you know any better way. Let me know. :)?

Comment: @ScottStroz, I had to take a chance. There are people in ColdFusion community who finds the bugs in the language itself and communicate with Adobe Engineers. Then there are people who have in-depth knowledge about the technology like you, Leigh, Henry, Adam and few others. Then Anit is also on Stackoverflow. Same might be true for PHP.

Comment: Having an 'in depth knowledge about the technology' does not mean we poses knowledge and/or understanding of the underlying mechanisms or the rationale behind the implementation of those mechanisms.

Comment: @ScottStroz, You are absolutely right. But as I said earlier, I took a chance. My philosophy is very simple- If you never ask, you will never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own wrapper.  My isEmail() UDF uses special rules for including/excluding test email addresses depending on IP. (I had to allow some specific IPs for testing.)  I also added a 2nd parameter to indicate type of validation... ColdFusion's BIF isValid("email") is the default, then there's regex, Java w/DNS (which respects DNS TTL) and Java w/o DNS.

Here's a regex UDF from CFLib.org:

http://www.cflib.org/udf/isEmail

```
function isEmail(str) {
    return (REFindNoCase("^['_a-z0-9-\+]+(\.['_a-z0-9-\+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.(([a-z]{2,3})|(aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|museum|name|jobs|post|pro|tel|travel|mobi))$",
arguments.str) AND len(listGetAt(arguments.str, 1, "@")) LTE 64 AND
len(listGetAt(arguments.str, 2, "@")) LTE 255) IS 1;
}
```

I prefer using Java because it has more features, better failure messages, optionally uses DNS (for TLD validation & MX record checking) and can be installed on ColdFusion 8-11. (I've found that reported bugs in currently supported versions of ColdFusion are fixed only in the latest or upcoming versions.)

There is a PHP version of the java class available. By using this, ColdFusion, PHP and C# results will be consistent.

https://code.google.com/p/isemail/downloads/list

If you want to try the Java implementation with ColdFusion, check out:

http://isemail.info/

Here's some sample code I blogged about here:

http://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/93979011009/better-coldfusion-email-validation-using-java

```
<cfscript>
/* Copy IsEMail.jar to java path. Download from https://code.google.com/p/isemail/downloads/list */
emails = ["test@test.com",
    "valid_but_no_mx@fake-domain.com",
    "valid_but_no_dns@fake-domain2.com",
    """much.more unusual""@example.com",
    "john.smith@example.com(comment)",
    """first\last""@iana.org",
    "first.last@com",
    """Joe.\Blow""@iana.org",
    "foobar@192.168.0.1",
    "first.last@-xample.com",
    "first.last@exampl-.com",
    "first.last@x234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234.iana.org"];

/* Set DNS server to prevent ColdFusion error:
   javax.naming.ConfigurationException: localhost:2932 is not a valid DNS pseudo-URL */
sys = createObject("java", "java.lang.System");
sys.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","dns:/YOUR_DNS_SERVER");

isEmailObj = CreateObject("java", "com.dominicsayers.isemail.IsEMail");
check_DNS = true;
responseLabels = ListToArray("Email,isValid,Status,Rule ID,Rule Name,SMTP SMTP Code");

function checkEmail(e, useDNS){
    var check = isEmailObj.is_email_verbose(e, Check_DNS);
    var response =  structNew();
    response["Email"] = e;
    response["isValid"] = check.getState().isValid();
    response["Status"] = check.getStatusTextExplanatory();
    response["Rule ID"] = check.getId();
    response["Rule Name"] = check.getConstantName();
    response["SMTP"] = "N/A";
    response["SMTP Code"] = "N/A";
    if (useDNS){
        response["SMTP"] = check.getSmtpCode();
        response["SMTP Code"] = check.getSmtpCodeText();
    }
    return response;
}

for(i=1; i LTE ArrayLen(emails); i=i+1){
    writeoutput('<h2>#emails[i]#</h2>');
    temp = checkEmail(emails[i], check_DNS);
    for(a=1; a LTE ArrayLen(responseLabels); a=a+1){
        if (StructKeyExists(temp, responseLabels[a])){
            writeoutput('<div><b>#responseLabels[a]#:</b> #Temp[responseLabels[a]]#</div>');
        }
    }
    writeoutput('<hr>');
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: The answer is not what I expected, but this is the most useful answer. So I marked it as accepted. Thanks for the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is further from the RFC standard than Coldfusion but closer to the general idea of what an email will most likely have:

- an @
- a FQDN - Fully Qualified Domain Name (i.e @mydomain.com)
- a TLD - Top Level Domain (i.e .com)
- an alpha-numeric + non-space word boundary username( i.e john.doe@...)

(Coldfusion does have all of these as well plus more, as your example points out)

Comment: Starting in ColdFusion 11, the "display name" as now part of a valid email address. I'm desperately hoping that this is a long-term unreported bug since CF2018u3 is still doing it.  As of this comment, the following strings are evaluated "true" when tested against isValid("email") even though they may be unrouteable: test@test; test@1.2.3.4; "test" <test@test.com>